# Why there is no primitive BiConsumer in java 8?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I am new to Java 8 and I can't find any primitive BiConsumer (IntBiConsumer etc), However There is a ToIntBiFunction which is the primitive specialization of the BiFunction. Also there is a IntBinaryOperator which is identical to ToIntBiFunction.

```
BiConsumer<Integer,String> wrappedBiConsumer = (i,s) -> System.out.printf("Consume %d %s \n",i,s);
ToIntBiFunction<String,String> toIntFunction = (a,b) -> a.length()* b.length();
```

1. Is there any reason why Oracle have not provided a IntBiConsumer with Java8 ?
2. Why there is two interfaces like "IntBinaryOperator" and "ToIntBiFunction" instead having a one interface like "IntBiFunction" ? ( if they are there to serve different purposes, still both of them can be extended from the same parent IntBiFunction)

I am pretty sure they designed it that way with a good reason and pls let me understand it.

Comment: If they included all possible combinations of functional interfaces with primitive types, the number of possibilities would explode.  I think they just picked the ones they thought would be most useful.  There's really no design reason why they couldn't have included it.

Comment: They had no APIs that needed it, so they didn't bother.

Comment: FWIW, I created a package available from Maven Central with just about every variant such as `IntBiConsumer` you could want - `com.mastfrog:function` - javadoc here: https://timboudreau.com/builds/job/mastfrog-parent/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/util/function/target/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see there's any specific reason behind excluding `IntBiConsumer`, it's a trivial `@FunctionalInterface` that you can easily implement if you need it. I guess that's the same reason for which we don't have `TriFunction` or `TriConsumer` interfaces.

Don't mix `IntBinaryOperator` with `ToIntBiFunction`. The first is a function of type `(int, int) -> int` while the latter is of the form `(T, U) -> int`. So the latter could at most be `(Integer, Integer) -> int` but this incurs in boxing of primitives inside objects which is far for performant. `IntBinaryOperator`, instead, keeps them unboxed, which is useful when you need more performance (and that can be the case with a binary int function).

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there is an `ObjIntConsumer` in Java which is a partial int-specialization of `BiConsumer`. So, your first example can be rewritten as:

```
ObjIntConsumer<String> consumer = (s, i) -> System.out.printf("Consume %d %s%n", i, s);
```